# Text file upload not working

Tags: php, html, post

I am trying to process an uploaded text file in PHP.

HTML

```
<p>Please upload file below:</p>

<form action="process.php" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="file" accept="text/plain">
      <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

// print the file metadata
print_r($_FILES);

?>
```

When I submit the form, I simply get an empty array printed: Array ( )

What am I doing wrong here? I want to be able to read the text file, line by line.

Comment: I think you are missing `enctype=multipart/form-data`

Comment: Thanks, works now.